# Suppress blank page after maketitle in memoir

Tags: memoir

I have been using the `\maketitle` with some customizations regarding the positions of the text and would like to add some more....

How could I suppress the blank page after the title page? 
I need to print this book with some information on the verso of the title page and it simply writes on the page after leaving one whole blank page.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,showtrims,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\title{MY TITLE}
\author{A GUY'S NAME}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{% usado pra criar título personalizado
    \centering{
    {\Large\theauthor}\par
    \vspace*{\fill}
    {\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}}\par
    \vspace*{\fill}
    1ª Edição\\
    Florianópolis, 2016\\
    Ed. EDITORS INFO
    }}


\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \maketitle %título  
    \end{titlingpage}
    This should be in title's verso
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is because of `openright` standard command from memoir, is there a way to only set the next page to start on the left?

Comment: Your example is not compilable and `\begin{center}...\end{center}` and additional `\centering` is not really useful, as is the `figure` environment. The title graphics is not supposed to float away, most likely!

Comment: OK, fixing that... @ChristianHupfer

Comment: There you go @ChristianHupfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my point of view there's no need to use the `titlingpage` environment: Just use `\maketitle` in conjunction with `\thispagestyle{empty}`.

I also cleaned up the `\maketitle` command a little bit!

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,showtrims,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{MY TITLE}
\author{A GUY'S NAME}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{% usado pra criar título personalizado
  \begin{center}
    {\Large\theauthor}\par
    \vspace*{\fill}
    {\Huge\textbf{\thetitle}}\par
    % \begin{figure}[h]
    %   \centering
    %   
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ente}

    \vspace*{\fill}
    1ª Edição\\
    Florianópolis, 2016\\
    Ed. EDITORS INFO
  \end{center}
}
\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\begin{document} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
  \maketitle %título  

\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Adriano: You're welcome. Happy TeXinG!